MIDIFlushOutput does not cancel events scheduled over network
Calling MIDIFlushOutput on a network endpoint is not cancelling events scheduled with future timestamps -- they continue to send. A OSStatus of 0 is returned, indicating the call was successful.
e.g.
func send(eventLists: [MIDIEventList]) {
    let outputPortRef = ...
    let networkDestination = ...

    for var eventList in eventLists {
        MIDISendEventList(outputPortRef, networkDestination.objectRef, &eventList)
    }
}

MIDIFlushOutput(networkDestination.objectRef)

I'm seeing that MIDIFlushOutput does successfully cancel scheduled events on a non-network endpoint. How can I clear all scheduled outgoing events over a MIDI Network connection?
